# Is there a way to invoke the new operator from CEF?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I'd like to create a CustomEvent object within a V8 context. I tried using .create() but the browser doesn't let me create it that way. Can you call the new operator from within CEF?

This was what I tried to invoke it with:

(C++ code)

```
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> globalObj = context->GetGlobal();

CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> customEvent = globalObj->GetValue("CustomEvent");
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> prototype = customEvent->GetValue("prototype");

CefV8ValueList prototypeArgs;
prototypeArgs.push_back(prototype);
prototypeArgs.push_back();

CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> object = globalObj->GetValue("Object");
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> create = object->GetValue("create");
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> event = create->ExecuteFunction(NULL, prototypeArgs);
```

I really want to just have a easy way from C++ to call

(Javascript Code)

```
new CustomEvent("test");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CefV8Context::Eval to execute the javascript code you need.

```
CefRefPtr<CefV8Value> returnValue;
CefRefPtr<CefV8Exception> exception;
context->Eval("new CustomEvent('test');", returnValue, exception);
```